# Filter the lowest values of a sql result every time a column changes

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Sorry for weird title its hard for me to explain what i need but i will do my best,

My table BehaviorHidraulics contains these columns:
[id],[siteIDDatagate],[datetime],[value],[channelnum],[channeltype], now i need to find the lowest value of [value] in a certain date and i've managed to do so with this query:

```
select  min(value) as minvalue, siteIDDatagate, channeltype, channelnum, datetime 
  from BehaviorHidraulic where channelnum = '1' and datetime 
  between '2021-10-10 00:00:00' and '2021-10-10 23:59:59' 
  group by siteIDDatagate, channeltype, channelnum, datetime order by siteIDDatagate, minvalue ASC
```

now this returns something like this:

```
minvalue  siteIDDatagate
26         _site_1003
26,39      _site_1003 
26,5       _site_1003 
17,20      _site_303
17,600     _site_303
58,200     _site_304
58,599     _site_304
```

and this is good but i need to ditch every result under the first row for every site so it could look like this:

```
minvalue  siteIDDatagate
26         _site_1003
17,20      _site_303
58,200     _site_304
```

i think i need to use the lag function but im not very good with SQL so please any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Remove excess columns from GROUP BY expression and output list.

Comment: remove datetime from grouü by or change it to DATE(datetime) and add datetime to the fiellist like select datetime ,.. your fields

Comment: @Akina this doesn't do what i requested, it just lowers the amount of columns in the result.

Comment: Yes, but what would you want to show in the other columns assumed the 'channeltype' column would for example group three or four different values

Comment: *this doesn't do what i requested, it just lowers the amount of columns in the result.* ??? but you have accepted the answer which realizes my approach precisely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the lag function will help you in this case. The lag function is a windowed function that allows you to access data in a previous row. Akina, posted what I think is the answer for you.

Currently your query is:

```
select  min(value) as minvalue, siteIDDatagate, channeltype, channelnum, datetime
  from BehaviorHidraulic where channelnum = '1' and datetime 
  between '2021-10-10 00:00:00' and '2021-10-10 23:59:59' 
  group by siteIDDatagate, channeltype, channelnum, datetime order by siteIDDatagate, minvalue ASC
```

The additional "group by" fields that you have are causing the excess rows. Your results seem to only care about `min(value)` and `siteIDDatagate` yet you're grouping on additional fields unnecessarily. You should consider rewriting the query as such:

```
select  min(value) as minvalue, siteIDDatagate
  from BehaviorHidraulic where channelnum = '1' and datetime 
  between '2021-10-10 00:00:00' and '2021-10-10 23:59:59' 
  group by siteIDDatagate order by siteIDDatagate, minvalue ASC
```

This will ensure that you only retrieve the minimum `value` over the date period specified for each `siteIDDatagate`.

If you shave other requirements, please specify.

Comment: This worked perfectly, and sorry Akina i think i missunderstood, what you said was correct. thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

You can use row_number() window function to find the first record (the one with minimum value). Here an is an exmaple

```
;with cte AS
(
  select siteIDDatagate, 
         channeltype, 
         channelnum, 
         datetime,
         value,
         row_number() over(PARTITION BY siteIDDatagate, channeltype, channelnum ORDER BY value) AS RN
  from BehaviorHidraulic where channelnum = '1' 
       and datetime between '2021-10-10 00:00:00' and '2021-10-10 23:59:59' 
)
SELECT *
FROM cte 
WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: it returns one row per site but it doesnt return the value itself

Comment: You just need to add 'Value' in the select list within the cte. The query has been updated.